# How to pull curl_exec info from string

Tags: php, curl

```
$appID='xxxxx';
$restID='xxxx';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data2);

$headers = array(
    'X-Parse-Application-Id: ' .$appID.'',
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ' .$restID.'',
    'Content-Type: image/jpeg'       
    );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, xxxxx);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

After `curl_exec()` I get a result of:

`{"name":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","url":"http://xxxxxxxx.com"}`

How can I pull the url `info(http://xxxxxxxx.com)` from the string?

Comment: Please show us the code you're using to perform the curl_exec.

Comment: I added the other code but I don't know why or how it's relevant

Comment: The code will help name the variable correctly when providing your answer, as Josua has now done. In addition, it's usually good form to include a reproducible example on stackoverflow questions.

Comment: @Greg change your content type to `Content-Type: application/json` and than use `json_decode` in your `$response`.

Comment: still debugging this?

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano no it's solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

you can try to add:

```
$result = json_decode($response);
echo $result->url; // or print_r($result);
```

Comment: @Greg This code is perfectly fine for what you said in your original question. Please revise your code update this post with relevant information.

Comment: if your $response value is {"name":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","url":"xxxxxxxx.com";} , you can do like my answer bro. if not might be youre wrong

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano everything works except the echo

Comment: what if print_r($result);

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the response you're getting:

`{"name":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","url":"http://xxxxxxxx.com"}`

is [JSON](http://json.org/).  If you're wanting to get the "url" part of the response, you first need to decode it with [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and then reference the part you want: `$result->url`.

```
$result = json_decode($response);
echo $result->url;
```